# Why do these white artifacts appear on animated GIFs in Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook-messenger

Animated GIFs that I send and receive in Facebook Messenger have square white artifacts. This also appears on the GIF previews when I search for GIFs to send. It appears to be on certain pixels that don't change throughout the GIF, could it be something compression related?

[image: White artifacts in Messenger gifs]